# Apply svg element to multiple svgs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Using JavaScript I'd like to create a svg circle element and then apply that element to multiple svgs - or to apply one svg to multiple divs. 
I know how to use the svg circle element multiple times within one svg - is there a similar way to do this with multiple svgs?

So far I only have the code to create all the elements, but I don't know what to do next. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
//Create circle template
var myElement = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
myElement.setAttribute("cx",5);
myElement.setAttribute("cy",5);
myElement.setAttribute("r",15);
myElement.setAttribute("id","Circle");

//Create the svgs
var div1 = document.getElementById('firstDiv');
var div2 = document.getElementById('secondDiv');
var svg1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var svg2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
div1.appendChild(svg1);
div2.appendChild(svg2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method cloneNode.
Sample

```
svg1.appendChild(myElement.cloneNode(true));
svg2.appendChild(myElement.cloneNode(true));
```

See
http://jsfiddle.net/kN76y/

Comment: Just what I was looking for :-)